# Will this code leak memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, memory

I am calling in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performReachabilityCheck) withObject:nil];`

Here is the performReachabilityCheck

```
-(void)performReachabilityCheck{
    internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReach startNotifer];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];
}
```

Do I need to create an auto-release pool? If so, how can I do that in this context?

UPDATE:
Is this the correct way to implement the auto-release pool?

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performReachabilityCheck) withObject:nil];
    [pool release]; pool = nil;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, anytime you perform a selector on a background thread, you need to wrap it in an AutoreleasePool. The classes you're using may create autoreleased objects. If you run this while connected to the debugger, you should see a lot of messages about "No autorelease pool in place, just leaking".

Comment: check my updated code. am i creating the auto-release pool correctly?

Comment: @Sheehan, you must put NSAutoreleasePool inside your performReachabilityCheck method (the one, that runs in background)